# Como fazer um array que aumente, caso o usuário deseje?

Tags: java, array, tabela-banco-de-dados

Estou com um problema num projeto de programação.
O programa pede o seguinte:

- Trata-se de um Banco de Dados de Questões (Por exemplo, um ENEM, ou Vestibular).
- Eu **PRECISO** fazer alguns comandos ,como adicionar alunos, professores, dizer quem você é, e se você 'não existe', adicioná-lo, mas essa parte já está concluída. Eu fiz ArrayList, para os dois (alguma sugestão? Estou aberto à qualquer coisa!)
- Eu preciso adicionar questões, caso você seja um professor. Eu fiz uma variável professor, que é `boolean`, e pode se "registrar" no programa como um, ou com um aluno. Porém, como eu faço `array` que aumente de tamanho, quando o professor adiciona novas questões? Eu fiz array de duas dimensões, pois eu preciso adicionar questões para cada ano *(Filosofia[QUESTÃO][ANO],Filosofia[3][0],Filosofia[3][1],Filosofia[3][2],questões diferentes, de anos diferentes!)*.
  E também, no que se trata as respostas de cada pergunta, eu fiz um outro array que tem o mesmo tamanho que o de perguntas, que corresponde à ele,por exemplo, um array de Sociologia, com X questões para os 3 anos, eu fiz um outro, de respostas, com os X questões, com cada resposta separada cada uma com um '|', para cada ano.

Alguma sugestão?
package projetofinal;

```
package projetofinal;

public class provaQuestoes {
    String[][] Biology = new String[0][3];
    String[][] BiologyAnswer = new String[0][3];
    //Claro que, para cada matéria, mas esse é só um exemplo

    String questionBiology(int year, int question){
        return Biology [year][question];
    }//Cada matéria tem um método que faz isso

    void chooseSubject(int y, int subject, int question){
        switch(subject){
            case 1:
                questionBiology(question, y);
                break;
               // Cada matéria tem um valor que corresponde a um método que envia uma pergunta,
               // porquê eu preciso também que eu crie um teste para o aluno,
               // mas isso é para depois

    [..]
    void addQuestion(int subject, String question, String answers,int y){
        switch(subject){
            case 1:
        \\insira o código aqui
            break;
```

Essa é uma classe que tem todas as disciplinas de cada ano. O Principal é outra classe, onde eu fiz um menu "decorado", tudo em texto, com um case, que permite cadastro de usuário(aluno/professor), entrada como um desses dois, com registro de nome, registro de questão e outras coisas.

Comment: É legal dar uma formatada na pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help . E colocar seu código é importante.

Comment: No caso você não está utilizando um banco de dados mesmo né? MySQL por exemplo?

Comment: Não, o 'banco de dados' seria o array mesmo, já que não sei programar nisso

Comment: Hmmm, entendi. Era bom se você pudesse postar o seu código, ta muito confuso de entender.

Comment: Vou postar, então

Comment: Beleza, posta ai que a tarde quando der um tempo eu respondo.

Comment: Você está **piorando** a formatação, por favor, não desfaça as melhorias de outros usuários. Confira o [histórico de edição](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/39825/revisions) para ver como é o padrão do site mostrado pelo 1º editor. O seguinte post também vale uma leitura: [**Oh, não! Editaram minha pergunta!**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2212/201), e a ajuda de formatação: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help . Obrigado.

Comment: Você consegue ver que o código está todo esculhambado ali encima, não? E é impossível consertar pq vc pôs HTML no meio do código. Conforme tinha dito antes, a formatação aqui é em Markdown.

Comment: @user3718717 Para podermos te ajudar e para a pergunta ser legível para futuros usuários com o mesmo problema, procure deixar o texto e os códigos bem formatados. De preferência, use os ícones do Editor de texto para criar os efeitos de lista, negrito e indentação de código - evite as tags HTML.

Releia o seu post também após terminar de escrevê-lo (imagine como você fosse sua mãe lendo o texto). Ele está confuso.

Answer (score 1):

Penso que tens que usar Array em casos em que tens um tamanho definido, que nunca mudará... Se acha que os dados vão aumentar, não use array, use outras estruturas de dados, como o ArrayList.

Se você já viu orientação a objectos veja:

Em vez de criar array para cada Materia, faça o seguinte:

1. Cria uma classe `Materia` com atributos `(id,nome)`;
2. Cria uma classe `Questao` com atributos `(id,materia,ano,questao,resposta)`

Assim sá terá que preencher o objecto `Questao` e adicionar no ArrayList.